# Adding links to document views in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, hyperlink

I would like to set up a template for a team site, prepared with our set of metadata etc. I am using SharePoint PnP for that purpose. One of the customizations I would like to do for the team sites, is that I would like to add links to the different views that we have in the document libraries.

In SharePoint On-Premises the links were looking like this (a very general path):
https://x.x.x/sites/x/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Meetings.aspx

But in SharePoint Online all I can get is a link that looks like this:
https://x.x.x/sites/x/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=13e029b4%2D8609%2D4266%2D8252%2D36b20af25584
(it is pointing to a specific view in this specific library)

How can I get a more general path to the views of a document library in SharePoint Online, that I can standardize across several sites?

Comment: It's same as on-premise, so you can use /Forms/Allitems.aspx , /Forms/Meetings.aspx. Query "?viewid="  changes view by ID without refreshing whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "old style" links still work, even though SharePoint uses a different redirection URL when switching views in the UI.

On any Modern View, if you choose the advanced option to "Edit this View", you get the old classic interface to configure view settings, including, at the very top, the URL to that view and the option to customize the view's page file name.